# Email Column IN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

there i a table which is userss table in this email i want to select email then the other table is document info table and in this table i select documnet name ,uploaded file,uploaded by and the other table is approve type in this table i select approve type and when user upload document info goes to document info table but i want to select email to send mail through respective emailid i try t select but i cant..here is sp

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[email]
@DepID int
  as
    SELECT     
     dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName, 
     dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded, 
   dbo.Department.DepType as Department, 
  dbo.DocumentInfo.UploadedBy as UploadedBy, 
   dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as Status
       FROM         dbo.DocumentInfo INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Approval ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID = dbo.Approval.DocID INNER
                         JOIN
                  dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.Approval.ApproveID =     
         dbo.ApproveType.ApproveID INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Userss on Userss.UserID =dbo.Userss.UserID inner join
                  dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID = dbo.Department.DepID
                  INNER JOIN
                  dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
                  where DocumentInfo.DepID=@DepID
```

this is userss table

```
 UserID  UserName Password UserTypeID  Email            DesgId 
   1     kety     cute         2       acv@ymail.com    4
   2     John     bravo        2       john@gmail.com   4
```

this is document info table

```
**DocId DocName       Uploadedfile DocTypeID DepID ApproveID UploadedBy UserID**
    18  hranaylsis    HR.docx        1         2    2         john         6
    19  ecoreport eco 2.docx         1         2    1         john         6
```

now how i select email in sp

Comment: longest sentence know to man

Comment: @OGHaza sorry what u do mean to say ?

Comment: what error do you get when you try to select the email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to join the tables based on UserName - I'll make that assumption.  I have also cleaned up your code a little bit to make it more readable.  It appears you were joining the UserId field in Userss to itself.

```
 SELECT 
    di.DocName as DocumentName, 
    di.Uploadfile as FileUploaded, 
    d.DepType as Department, 
    di.UploadedBy as UploadedBy, 
    at.ApproveType as Status,
    u.Email as UserEmail
FROM dbo.DocumentInfo di 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Approval a 
       ON di.DocID = a.DocID 
       INNER JOIN dbo.ApproveType at
       ON a.ApproveID =  at.ApproveID 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Userss u
       ON u.UserId = di.UserId 
       INNER JOIN dbo.Department d 
       ON di.DepID = d.DepID
       INNER JOIN dbo.DocType  dct
       ON di.DocTypeID = dct.DocTypeID
where di.DepID= @DepID
```

Comment: Happy to help.  Any other errors just post to the comment and we can resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly joining to your `Userss` table.

I have cleaned up your query a bit. Instead of writing out the whole table name each time, you can give each table an alias, this makes queries look a lot easier to read.

```
SELECT     
    di.DocName AS DocumentName, 
    di.Uploadfile AS FileUploaded, 
    di.UploadedBy AS UploadedBy, 
    d.DepType AS Department, 
    at.ApproveType AS Status,
    u.Email 
FROM dbo.DocumentInfo di
INNER JOIN dbo.Approval a ON di.DocID = a.DocID 
INNER JOIN dbo.ApproveType at ON a.ApproveID = at.ApproveID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Userss u ON di.UserID = u.UserID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Department d ON di.DepID = d.DepID
WHERE di.DepID = @DepID
```

That may work immediately, otherwise let me know what error is shown.